# Вопрос по парсингу сайта с использованием JSOUP

Tags: android, jsoup

Только начал разбираться с парсингом сайтов с использование jsoup и застрял на этом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу вытянуть текст под атрибутом alt и ссылку (src).
Пытался добраться таким образом, но безуспешно

```
Element element = document.getElementById("dle-content");
Elements mainNewsBlock = element.select("main-news");
Elements mainNewsAllBlock = mainNewsBlock.select("main-news-all");
Elements mainNewsImage = mainNewsAllBlock.select("main-news-image");
Elements aBlock = mainNewsImage.select("a");
Elements spanBlock = aBlock.select("span.main-news-img-fon");
Elements imgBlock = spanBlock.select("img");
Log.d(TAG, imgBlock.attr("alt").toString());
Log.d(TAG, imgBlock.attr("src").toString());
```

Что не так, народ подскажите?

Кроме того `< div id="dle-content" >...< /div >`
имеет пять вложенных `< div class="main-news" >...< /div >`

То есть мне надо вытащить пять ссылок и пять строк (alt).
Как в этом случае обойтись без дублирования?

Comment: `mainNewsBlock` имеет тип `Elements`, а тот позволяет получить список элементов, т.е. в нем будут ваши 5 элементов `.main-news`. Вам останется в цикле перебрать `mainNewsBlock` и для каждого элемента получить ссылку и строку

Comment: Понял Вас спасибо, но что не так может быть с моим кодом. У меня не получается вытащить ссылку и текст в логах?

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался: в строковый аргумент нужно добавлять "**div.**name_class"
то есть
Elements mainNewsAllBlock = mainNewsBlock.select("div.main-news-all");
и далее по ангалогии